# multidimensional jagged map

Tags: c++, linux, dictionary, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm a c++ noob trying to build a personal finance websocket server that tracks all of my assets and liabilities in real-time.

I've found that I can make `map`s of `map`s to have a multi-dimensional system of key-value pairs.

I've also found that `boost::any` and `boost::variant` can be used to store multiple types for a values.  My problem is that some levels aren't very complex compared to others.  For example, a bank account will only have a value, the amount in the account, while a brokerage account will have many types of investments and characteristics, so I'd like to do something like (in json):

```
{
    'bankAccount': 100.00,
    'brokerageAccount': {
        'stocks': {
            'companyName': 'Stack Exchange',
            'ticker': 'STAK',
            'pps': bazillion
            ...
```

Where `bankAccount` and `brokerageAccount` can be `insert`ed and `erase`d when needed and discarded as necessary.

I don't really know where to go from here.  When I try to put

```
map<string, boost::any> accounts;
accounts["cash"] = 100;
accounts["brokerageAccount"] = map<string, boost::any>;
```

in the `private` section of `broadcast_server` in this [websocket server](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp), `gcc` with these flags `-I ~/websocketpp-master/ -std=c++0x -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system -L/usr/lib -pthread -O0 -ljson_spirit` gives `error: ‘accounts’ does not name a type` for the last two lines.

How best can I store data in a json type way above, with the ability to add and delete keys and values anywhere?

Comment: For reasons of debugging and efficiency, I would suggest you make real types for your data once you have a data model figured out. In the present, `unordered_map` (a hash table) may give you better performance than `map` (a balanced tree) for `string` keys.

Comment: @JonPurdy Thank you for the performance tip!  Would you mind explaining what you mean by "real types"?  I'm still very noob.  Also, if you have a suggestion for a totally different methodology, absolutely please post it!  I'm not married to this at all, I just want it to work all in one container so that I can have it all in one place without duplication of accounts, subaccounts, etc.  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: I mean that the ability to add and remove values arbitrarily may help you *figure out* what you would like the structure of your data to be, but once you know that structure, you can create your own classes that model your specific problem. In particular, a class can enforce invariants on its values, such as numeric ranges. It is also a compile-time error to access nonexistent or wrongly typed data members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accounts["brokerageAccount"] = map<string, boost::any>;
```

You can not assign type to object.
To fix problem add **()**

```
accounts["brokerageAccount"] = map<string, boost::any>();
```

Variant that should be compiled correctly is:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, boost::any> accounts;
   accounts["cash"] = 100;
   accounts["brokerageAccount"] = std::map<std::string, boost::any>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this!  Do you know how to do this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808339/set-access-jagged-map-values-made-with-mapstring-boostany?lq=1  I very much appreciate it in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`map<string, boost::any>` on the last line is a type, not an object of that type.  You have to call the constructor of that type to create an argument.  Change the last line to

```
accounts["brokerageAccount"] = map<string, boost::any>();
```

This fixes it on my copy of Visual Studio 2010