# set/access jagged map values made with map<string, boost::any>

Tags: c++, dictionary, jagged-arrays, boost-any, json-spirit

I've been [shown how to create a jagged multidimensional `std::map` by using `boost::any`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805706/1382306).

However, I'm having trouble setting the values like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247956/1382306).

When I use

```
accounts["bank"]["cash"] = 100;
```

`gcc` gives this error

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘accounts.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, 
_Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char>, boost::any, 
std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const 
std::basic_string<char>, boost::any> > >((* & std::basic_string<char>(((const 
char*)"bank"), (*(const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))["cash"]’
```

How can a jagged multidimensional `map` created with `boost::any` be accessed?  (If there is a better technique to do this, please show me.  I only care about what works and is quick to write.)

**multidimensional declaration**

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> accounts;
accounts["bank"] = std::map<std::string, boost::any>();
accounts["bank"]["cash"] = 100;
```

**[json-spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented)**

I gave up and tried to use json-spirit's `mObject` instead since all of this seems already built in.

Funny thing is is that with the exact same notation, I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> accounts;
accounts["bank"] = std::map<std::string, boost::any>();
accounts["bank"]["cash"] = 100;
```

Of course this cause compile time error, you put to boost::any std::map,
but compiler have no idea about this. accounts["bank"] has "boost::any" type,
and boost::any have no

```
int& operator[](const char *)
```

Read how boost::any works: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any/s02.html

Fix is trivial:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, boost::any> accounts;
  accounts["cash"] = 100;
  accounts["bank"] = std::map<std::string, boost::any>();
  boost::any_cast<std::map<std::string, boost::any> &>(accounts["bank"])["cash"] = 100;
}
```

Comment: lol.  I was going to do that as a last resort.  Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your accounts map? As boris said, you need to nest two maps together in order to do what you want.

Replace the type string with boost::any

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, map<string, string>> accounts;

    accounts["bank"]["cash"] = "infinity";

    cout << accounts["bank"]["cash"];

    return 0;
}
```

#### How does this work?

- Maps are key and value pairs.

accounts["bank"] returns the value of the outermost map, which corresponds to

```
map<string, **map<string, string>**>
```

accounts["bank"]["cash"] returns the value of the innermost map, which corresponds to

```
map<string, map<string, **string**>>
```

---

Defining a 1 dimensional map does not allow you to do what you want, but 2 dimensional maps do.

Comment: Thank you Steven.  Please see my edit for more details on how I declared & initialized.

Comment: Ok, replace your first line with std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, boost::any>> accounts; and delete your second line. It should work now.

Comment: hmmm, i need to be able to append values as in the first linked question.  thanks anyways!